# jQuery DataTable - select number of result

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery DataTable and I want call my function when I select number of results from dropdown. How can I do that?

DataTable generate code:

```
<div id="displayData_length" class="dataTables_length">
  <label>
     Show <select name="displayData_length" size="1" aria-controls="displayData">
             <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
             <option value="25">25</option>
             <option value="50">50</option>
             <option value="100">100</option>
           </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

So i try use function:

```
$('select[name=displayData_length]').bind('change', function(event) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

But it is not good, because I don't see alert() when I select number of result.

How can I do that? Maybe is another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have tested your code - it works fine and as expected here. Be sure that the script is placed *after* the `<div id="displayData_length"`-markup.

If the markup is generated runtime by DataTables, place the function in a document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=displayData_length]').bind('change', function(event) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: and the `bind` happends _after_ your `.dataTable({` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.live()` instead of `.bind()`